# Moving millions of documents from Mongo to Kafka

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka

I have 10 Millions of documents in Mongo DB which I would like to push to Kafka as a JSON as it is without any change.

Looking for the best approaches.

1.Use Mongo reactive streams

```
 Flux.from(collection.find()).doOnError(e -> {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }).doOnComplete(() -> {
             System.out.println("Finished ");
         }).subscribe(doc -> {
             // Code to insert into Kafka
         });
```

2. Using Akka Stream

Is there any other connector available?

Also, Do i need to do multi threading inside subscribe method?

Any other better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) and [MongoDB source connector](https://github.com/DataReply/kafka-connect-mongodb) in order to replicate data from Mongo to Kafka. Using Kafka Connect is much more flexible, scalable and simple.

An example configuration would be:

```
name=mongodb-source-connector
connector.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongodbSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
batch.size=100
schema.name=yourSchemaName
topic.prefix=aPrefix # optional
databases=mydb.test,mydb.test2
```

Comment: +1 for using Kafka Connect. Another connector to look at is [Debezium](http://debezium.io/) which supports streaming from MongoDB

Comment: Does mongodb source connector support x509 based auth?

Comment: Kafka Connect supports SSL authentication. https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html#kafka-connect